# Write two separate lists to csv with headers in python

Tags: python

```
list1 = [1,2,4,5,7,8,9]  corresponds to ID
list2 = [3,2,1,1,1,2,3]  corresponds to relevance
```

I have two different lists say list1,list2 with numerical values in it. I want to write both to a csv file with headers ["ID","Relevance"]. Now I want to write values of list1 in header "ID" and list2 in header "Relevance". I have written below code trying to write both lists but it doesnt give desired output.

I want output to be in below sample format:

```
ID    Relevance
1         3
3         2
4         2
6         1
7         3
10        1
```

code:

```
with open('results_cosine11.csv', 'w', encoding="ISO-8859-1", newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    for value in list1,list2:
        wr.writerow([value])
```

Comment: Post the code *properly formatted*, tell us what it did wrong, and tell us what you did to try to fix it.

Comment: @Malvolio I have tried every possible code from stackover flow, but I could not get expected results. Above posted code is the final code which I am preferring currently.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). This will work:

```
with open('results_cosine11.csv', 'w', encoding="ISO-8859-1", newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    for value in zip(list1,list2):
        wr.writerow(value)
```

Or, more efficiently:

```
with open('results_cosine11.csv', 'w', encoding="ISO-8859-1", newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerows(zip(list1,list2))
```

---

In order to write the header too:

```
with open('results_cosine11.csv', 'w', encoding="ISO-8859-1", newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerow(("ID", "Relevance"))
    wr.writerows(zip(list1,list2))
```

Comment: `wr.writerows(zip(list1, list2))` works too, without the need for creating a temporary list to consume the map.

Comment: @bharel I also want to write headers in first row as ID, Relevance

Comment: @Ilja -- the `writerows` interface still creates the temporary list.  The list is never _named_ (the expression is resolved anonymously and passed as the actual parameter to writerows), which is a good thing, because the programmer (and the garbage collector) knows that the zipped list will never be reused, but no great savings of resources.

Comment: @Malvolio `zip()` is a generator in python 3. Are you sure `writerows` internally creates a list? I believe it's useless.

Comment: @Malvolio what Bharel said. There's `izip` for the python2 people. I did not check whether or not writerows materializes iterators internally, but as also said in previous comment there's at least no need for that. And what "interface"?

Comment: @Malvolio also the garbage collector will know very little about a temporary list, unless it somehow ends up in cyclic references. CPython uses refcounting, which handles most cases.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
a= zip(list1,list2)
for id,relevance in a:
   #... do  whatever
```